# ORA-00903 when merging on an updatable view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I get an ORA-00903 when merging into an otherwise updatable view in Oracle 11gR2 (USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS shows all columns insertable, updatable, deletable for base and view)

Standard Insert, Update, Delete all work normally.

The docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606
has the following:

> Use the INTO clause to specify the target table or view you are
>   updating or inserting into. In order to merge data into a view, the
>   view must be updatable. Refer to "Notes on Updatable Views" for more
>   information.

The updatable view criteria appear to be met in the following example, but the ORA-00903 is present in all merge attempts.  Changes to the instead of trigger don't appear to have any impact on mergability.

```
CREATE TABLE MERGE_TEST_B
(MERGE_TEST_ID   NUMBER              NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 MERGE_TEST_DESC VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MERGE_TEST_V
AS
  SELECT
    MERGE_TEST_B.MERGE_TEST_ID,
    MERGE_TEST_B.MERGE_TEST_DESC
  FROM MERGE_TEST_B;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MERGE_TEST_V_TIX
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MERGE_TEST_V
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TESTING VIEW MERGE.');
  END;
/
```

I wondered if there is a change that can can get this view into a mergable state, or whether this is ineligible.

The following attempt fails:

```
MERGE INTO MERGE_TEST_V
USING
  (SELECT
     'TESTMERGE' MERGE_TEST_DESC
   FROM DUAL) TEST_DATA
ON (MERGE_TEST_V.MERGE_TEST_DESC = TEST_DATA.MERGE_TEST_DESC)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
  (MERGE_TEST_ID, MERGE_TEST_DESC)
VALUES
  (-100, TEST_DATA.MERGE_TEST_DESC);
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why Oracle returns `ORA-00903` instead of `ORA-38106`, but the issue appears to be your trigger.  Dropping the trigger will allow your merge to work.

According to the description of [ORA-38106](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e38001.htm#ORA-38106), "When using MERGE to modify a view, you must only specify a single table in the view, **and the view cannot have an INSTEAD OF trigger.**"  [emphasis mine]

Almost buried in the documentation on the merge statement, this is actually **[mentioned](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF55642)**

Comment: Sure enough, runs fine without the trigger.  Thanks